# Missing mongodb.conf on FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: mongodb, freebsd

After having installed MongoDB 2.6.12 for FreeBSD 10.2, I need to change some MongoDB configuration parameters but there seems to be a problem.

- there is no mongodb.conf file in the directory /etc/
- instead, I located a mongodb.conf under usr/local/etc/ but the file is empty!?

I don't get it, what is wrong? MongoDB installation routine did not prompt any errors, hence I was expecting a fully operational mongodb.conf under /etc/

How am I supposed to change the MongoDB configuration now? Simply add the desired entries to the existing file under usr/local/etc/?

Comment: The usual location for application configuration in FreeBSD is `/usr/local/etc`.  `/etc` is for system configuration files.

Comment: Yes and that's (/usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf) where a mongodb.conf file is stored but for some strange reason it is empty, how can that be? According to the docs, I was expecting plenty of configuration options in there...

Answer (score 0):

The correct location is `/usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf`, and the file is supposed to be empty.  All you need is to add something like `dbpath=/usr/data/db` (or wherever you have created the directory to host your database) to be able to start the server.